# how to fixed dynamic link library Kernel32.dll Error in Window Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, kernel32

I have an angular application for which I have written an URL rewrite on the web.config file.
I am publishing my application on IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008).

To manage and enable URL Rewrite I want to install IIS URL Rewrite Module 2 at Server 2008.
While installing getting errors [The procedure entry point setDefaultDllDirectories could not be location the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udcp9.jpg).

How to get rid of this error.

While searching solution gets suggestions to update the window but I don't want to update the windows.

https://superuser.com/questions/1492060/procedure-entry-point-setdefaultdlldirectories-could-not-be-located-kernel32-dll

above link doesn't seem to work for me.